# WordPress how do I change images used in plugins?

Tags: plugins, images

One of my plugins has an ugly no-thumbnail picture. The url to this image is

> /wp-content/plugins/weblibrarian/images/nothumb.png

I am an admin. How do I change this image, without using FTP?

Comment: It's hard to give a definite answer without more context. But you could try css. Or see the plugin has a hook or filter to change it.

Comment: please consider asking in the plugin's support at https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/weblibrarian/